# How to pass parameters for multisignature addresses from Perl to the JSON::RPC::Client?

Tags: development, json-rpc, multi-signature, perl

I'm trying to create a multisig address with JSON::RPC::Client but I don't know how to pass the parameters. I can pass simple params such as in `validateaddress` that requires only `<bitcoinaddress>`. Working example:

```
$obj = { method  => 'validateaddress', params => ["$just_a_bit_address_in_string"],};
$res = $client->call($uri, $obj);
```

But when it comes to other types of parameters such as in `createmultisig`,  that the required params are `< nrequired > <'["key,"key"]'>`, I don't know to pass it to `$obj`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `["key,"key"]` part of the documentation means that it expects an array.

You need to call it like this:

```
$obj = {method  => 'createmultisig', params => [2, ["$key1", "$key2"]],};
$res = $client->call($uri, $obj);
```